# How to name objects of a class in c++ numerically?

Tags: c++, class

I am creating a program that will read information from a file and use it to create an object for my class Single.

Right now all I have is a person's name and then their age on the following line in the format:

`name
age
name
age etc.`

I am trying to use a for loop to create an object and name it based on the i value in the loop (the first object is "0", second is "1", etc.).

Does anybody know how I could accomplish this? Everything I try comes up with an error, the most common being redefinition of int i to Single, which makes sense to me. I just need to know if this is possible. Thanks!

Comment: I advise you forget about it. This is what arrays/containers are for.

Comment: Please use a `std::vector`, or even just an array for this.

Comment: I tried a few different things with arrays. It became complicated because the information is not all the same data type.

Comment: There are numbers of ways to work around that. Like polymorphism, `boost::variant` and `boost::any` types, etc. You need to explain your specific problem instead of asking *"how do I do this thing that's impossible in C++?"*.

Comment: @jrok If boost implemented a solution, it's de facto not impossible ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you catch yourself numbering your variables, you are in a scenario where you should use a container. This can be as simple as an array

```
int numbers[20];
```

or as complex as an `std::` container like `vector` or `list`:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
std::list<int> more_numbers;
```

Don't forget to

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
```

if you use the standard containers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this falls under the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

As far as I understand your intention, you have multiple options:

- Instead of doing what you currently do, create a class that represents the content of the file (one `std::string` field, on `int` field) and read two lines in every loop iteration.
- Create two `std::vector`s, one for `std::string`s and one for `int`s, and alternate between these two with every loop iteration. E.g. `if(i%2 == 0) /* read and insert into string vector */`.

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be done in a container.  Since you're reading from a file you're most likely going to want to do this in a 'while' loop instead of a 'for' loop during the "while(inputFileStream.read())".  Create the vector before the loop and populate it during the loop with the "push_back()" function for vector.

I'm not sure exactly how your file is setup to be read, but it would be easier to have the file delimited with the information you need for each object on the same line, you could store each piece in a temporary variable and then instantiate your object.  For instance, assuming you made a constructor for your object "Object object(temp1, temp2)" then simply "v.push_back(object)"

Hope this helps.